# SetSystemCursor() for multiple cursors behavior

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to change multiple cursors to `Cross cursor`. This is the code I am using for that matter:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetSystemCursor(IntPtr hcur, uint id);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr LoadCursor(IntPtr hInstance, int lpCursorName);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern Int32 SystemParametersInfo(UInt32 uiAction, 
    UInt32 uiParam, String pvParam, UInt32 fWinIni);

//Normal cursor
private static uint OCR_NORMAL = 32512;
//The text selection (I-beam) cursor.
private static uint OCR_IBEAM = 32513;
//The cross-shaped cursor.
private static uint OCR_CROSS = 32515;
```

Then I use these two functions I made:

```
static public void ChangeCursors() {
    SetSystemCursor(LoadCursor(IntPtr.Zero, (int)OCR_CROSS), OCR_NORMAL);
    SetSystemCursor(LoadCursor(IntPtr.Zero, (int)OCR_CROSS), OCR_IBEAM);
}

static public void RevertCursors() {
    SystemParametersInfo(0x0057, 0, null, 0);
}
```

If I just use `SetSystemCursor(LoadCursor(IntPtr.Zero, (int)OCR_CROSS), OCR_NORMAL);`, everything works fine. The `Normal cursor` gets replaced by `Cross cursor`.

My problem is when I try to change **multiple cursors** to `Cross cursor`. If I call `ChangeCursors()`, the expected result would be `Normal cursor` AND `I-beam cursor` gets replaced by `Cross cursor`. But the result is something really weird.

When the software starts depending on the current state of the cursor when the program started, the following strange things happen:

- If cursor was `Normal` when the software started, it changes to `Cross` (that's good). Also, `I-beam` is replaced with `Normal` (that's bad, it should be `Cross`).
- If cursor was `I-beam` when the software started, it stays `I-beam`(that's bad, because it should be `Cross`). Then, by hovering over to where previously the cursor should be `Normal` it is now `Cross` (that's good). Then, if I hover over to where the cursor was `I-beam` 1 second ago, it magically changes to `Normal` (that's weird) and stays that way.

So, my question is, how can I change 2 or more `Cursors` to `Cross cursor`, using `SetSystemCursor()` ?

Comment: The cursors are getting swapped right?

Comment: @Sayka the cursors are getting changed. The problem is when I try to change 2 or more cursors to `cross` cursor

Comment: Yes. Its swapping. When you assign Normal to Cross, the Cross becomes normal. After that when you assign IBeam to Cross, Now the Cross is Normal, so IBeam gets Normal and Cross gets IBeam, and like so..

Comment: @Sayka I think you are right. Any idea how to make this work as intended then ? Maybe with the use of `CopyCursor()` which I have no idea how to use or if it exists ?

Comment: Yes i found a function called CopyCursor from MSDN. Same as from user32.dll. Let me try. It might work

Comment: Have you tried CopyCursor?. It is showing as Entrypoint not found in my system. My system is x64 Win8.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dont get confused about the weird behaviour. It's just the cursors getting swapped each time when you Assign.

At first

```
Normal  ==  Normal
IBeam   ==  IBeam
Cross   ==  Cross
```

You Assign Normal = Cross

```
Normal  ==  Cross
IBeam   ==  IBeam
Cross   ==  Normal
```

And now assign IBeam = Cross (Which is Normal now)

```
Normal  ==  Cross
IBeam   ==  Normal
Cross   ==  IBeam
```

So for not letting it get swapped, you have to keep copies of all the cursors. I'll give you an example having Normal and IBeam changed to CROSS.

**Program.cs**

```
static class Program
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool SetSystemCursor(IntPtr hcur, uint id);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr LoadCursor(IntPtr hInstance, int lpCursorName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern Int32 SystemParametersInfo(UInt32 uiAction, UInt32
    uiParam, String pvParam, UInt32 fWinIni);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr CopyIcon(IntPtr pcur);

    private static uint CROSS = 32515;
    private static uint NORMAL = 32512;
    private static uint IBEAM = 32513;
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        uint[] Cursors = {NORMAL, IBEAM};

        for (int i = 0; i < Cursors.Length; i++)
            SetSystemCursor(CopyIcon(LoadCursor(IntPtr.Zero, (int)CROSS)), Cursors[i]);

        Application.Run(new Form1());
        SystemParametersInfo(0x0057, 0, null, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, you are right: the cursor **are** getting swapped. Very good that you found this out. I stand corrected.

Comment: And got this similar one CopyIcon

Comment: `CopyCursor` is just an alias for `CopyIcon`.

Comment: @MicroVirus Now we found out why I got the same results when I tried calling `SetSystemCursor()` with different order in the parameters.

Answer (score 2):

[`SetSystemCursor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648395%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  replaces the system cursor given by the second argument (`OCR_CROSS` in this example) with the cursor in the first argument. So, you set the `OCR_CROSS` cursor first to Normal, then to IBeam, so in effect the cross-cursor is set to look like an IBeam.

The documentation also specifically says

> The system destroys hcur [the first argument] by calling the DestroyCursor function. Therefore, hcur cannot be a cursor loaded using the LoadCursor function. To specify a cursor loaded from a resource, copy the cursor using the CopyCursor function, then pass the copy to SetSystemCursor.

Your code does this, so things could go wrong here, or at the least leak handles.

---

### In-depth look

The `SetSystemCursor` is far more invasive then you might think. It actually **swaps** the global cursor-data of the specified cursor in the second argument by the cursor object in the first argument.

This has consequences. Say that you replaced `IDC_WAIT` by `IDC_CROSS` and then `IDC_ARROW` by `IDC_WAIT` (code in C):

```
HCURSOR hCursor = LoadCursor(0, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_CROSS));
HCURSOR hCopyCursor = CopyCursor(hCursor);
SetSystemCursor(hCopyCursor, (DWORD)IDC_WAIT); // Replace Wait by Cross
HCURSOR hCursor2 = LoadCursor(0, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_WAIT)); // Load whatever is in Wait and put it in Arrow
HCURSOR hCopyCursor2 = CopyCursor(hCursor2);
SetSystemCursor(hCopyCursor2, (DWORD)IDC_ARROW); // Replace Arrow by Wait.
```

*Question*: Is the Arrow cursor of the system a Cross or a Wait cursor?

*Answer*: It's a Cross cursor.

The reason this happens is because you actually swap the underlying cursor data, not just some reference, so `LoadCursor` reads the replaced cursor data.

This also shows why it gets very confusing when you don't make a copy of the cursor first: then the two cursors are getting swapped globally.

Comment: You're doing exactly the opposite. From MSDN: "Enables an application to customize the system cursors. It replaces the contents of the system cursor specified by the id parameter [second argument] with the contents of the cursor specified by the hcur parameter [first argument] and then destroys hcur.". Applying this to your code: OCR_CROSS is replaced by OCR_NORMAL.

Comment: `SetSystemCursor(LoadCursor(IntPtr.Zero, (int)OCR_CROSS), OCR_NORMAL);` and  `SetSystemCursor(LoadCursor(IntPtr.Zero, (int)OCR_NORMAL), OCR_CROSS);` gives me exactly the same result. How is this even possible ? So, what are you suggesting here other than I am doing it wrong ? How could I change both `I-beam` and `normal` cursors to `cross` ? I tried every possible combination and nothing works. My default cursor on the form (even though the cursor is never on the form is `Default` if that matters)

Comment: I think there's issue pertaining to the second part of my answer, relating to the `DestroyCursor` call; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27112845/winapi-setsystemcursor-and-loadcursorfrom-how-to-set-default-cursor

Comment: I've updated my answer with an explanation of what happens and why you get behaviour that you did not expect.

Comment: The thing is, I don't replace `cursor A to cursor B` and then `cursor C to cursor A`. I want to replace `cursor A and B` to `cursor C`. Am I misunderstanding what you are saying ? I want to change **all cursors** to `Cross`. How can I do that ? I am using C# by the way. That code is in C++, but its similar.

Comment: That's also what I'm saying the entire time, and what's at the start of my answer. Look at your code and look at my code. You are doing it opposite! `SetSystemCursor(LoadCursor(IntPtr.Zero, (int)OCR_NORMAL), OCR_CROSS)` replaces the **Cross** cursor with the **Normal** cursor. So, reverse the `OCR_NORMAL` and `OCR_CROSS` to get what you want, and replace normal by cross. Finally, I really do suggest implementing it the way I do in my example, by using `CopyCursor` to avoid trouble.

Comment: If it was as simple as changing the order of the parameters, I would have figured it out myself. I have spent almost the whole day trying to change the cursor, so its safe to say that I have tried every possible combination of the order of parameters / order of function calls. I mentioned that in my first comment. If you actually have a working solution please post that instead of posting code of a different language about a different (but similar) problem. I just want to change `I-beam` and `Normal` cursor to `Cross` cursor...

Comment: And yet you posted code that is wrong on two critical points: the order of the arguments and the use of `LoadCursor` while this is specifically discouraged. How can you hope to get code that works if it's already wrong right from the start. Write the proper code, using my answer as a guide, and then and only then see what works and what doesn't.

Comment: Let me edit that. The `LoadCursor` is the only thing I found when I searched for it. I don't see any `CopyCursor` in C#, do you ? Also, with the edited code (switched order of arguments) I get the **same** result exactly as before

Comment: You are using PInvoke, so I thought you understood that you are using Windows API. `CopyCursor` is also a function in the Windows API, which you can import in the same manner.